# Como pegar LAST_INSERT_ID() de uma função mysqli_multi_query() com SET e INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

esse é o meu 'método 'de Cadastrar Apostas no meu sistema de apostas.

Nesse metodo, eu cadastro dados em duas tabelas, uma chamada BET e outra BET_MATCHES, o sistema é controlado por horário, por isso em todos os cadastros eu preciso setar o TIME_ZONE = '-03:00' para ter certeza que não vai haver erro nenhum no horário, e logo após isso executar a query que cadastra o cabeçalho e gera o ID da aposta.

Só que quando vou resgatar o ultimo id gerado nessa multi_query o código me retorna = 0... o que posso fazer ?

```
public function setBet($punter_name, $punter_phone, $value, $colab_id, $array_matches)
{
    // Post Header and Catch Bet ID
    $query =    "SET TIME_ZONE = '-03:00';";
    $query .= "INSERT INTO bet SET id ='NULL',
        punter_name ='$punter_name',
        punter_phone ='$punter_phone',
        value ='$value',
        colab_id ='$colab_id',
        date_time = now()";
    $data = mysqli_multi_query(Conexao::conectar(), $query) or die(Conexao::conectar());
    // For if data True, registered Header
    if ($data){
        // Get the id what we want
        $query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM bet";
        $data = mysqli_query(Conexao::conectar(), $query);
        $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
        var_dump($line);
    }
    else
        echo "There was an error when registering the bet header";  
}
```

Comment: Realmente precisa do `multi_query()`?

Comment: @rray preciso por causa do SET TIME_ZONE = '-03:00'; antes do insert que precisa ter a hora exata do Brasil para que não haja erro na conferencia das apostas

Comment: vc pode jogar isso na configuração do servidor se quiser.

Comment: @rray é que estou hospedando o sistema em um servidor compartilhado o qual não tenho poder de Super User no banco de Dados, e digamos que por se tratar de um sistema que movimenta valores em apostas baseado em horarios, posso dizer que quanto mais certeza melhor né ?

Comment: PHP não é a minha, mas quando você chama "Conexao::conectar()" você não está criando uma sessão com o banco de dados? Se for, então seu INSERT e seu SELECT não estão em sessões diferentes e por isso você não recebe o retorno? Neste caso, você deveria criar a conexão antes do INSERT e usar ela para o SELECT também, fechando em seguida.

Comment: @lpacheco vou testar e posto aqui se funcionar ! mas gostei da sua resposta !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então a solução que encontrei foi baseada na resposta do 
@Miguel e do @lpacheco

Veja o código

```
...
$conn = Conexao::conectar(); 
$query = "SET TIME_ZONE = '-03:00';";
$conn->query($query) or die('Erro na definição da timezone, tente mais tarde');
$query = "INSERT INTO bet (id, punter_name, punter_phone, value, colab_id, date_time, possible_prize) values(NULL, '$punter_name', '$punter_phone', '$value', '$colab_id', now(), 0);";
$data = $conn->query($query) or die('Erro na inserção, tente mais tarde');
$lastId = $conn->insert_id; // aqui guarda este e só este id, desta conecção que inseriu o novo dado

$query = "SELECT * FROM bet WHERE id=" .$lastId;
$data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
...
```

armazene a conexão em uma variável (isso fará com que toda query que vc chamar seja executada na mesma sessão do mysql) daí é só chamar uma de cada vez, sem a necessidade da multi_query.

assim você consegue pegar o id do último insert.

Comment: Não use caixa alta sem necessidade, não escreva *"resposta:"*, no momento que clica no botão "Publique sua Resposta" você já esta fazendo uma resposta. Entenda como criticas construtivas [editado]